# How can I run pg_dumpall with Heroku?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, pg-dumpall

How can I use `pg_dumpall` with Heroku? The default "database backup" feature from Heroku is `pg_dump` with the click of a button, which doesn't include roles, so I want to do `pg_dumpall` ... I'm trying `pg_dumpall -h myherokuurl.compute-1.amazonaws.com -l mypassword -U myUser > dump.sql`

I'm getting this error:

```
pg_dumpall: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for table pg_authid
pg_dumpall: error: query was: SELECT oid, rolname, rolsuper, rolinherit, rolcreaterole, rolcreatedb, rolcanlogin, rolconnlimit, rolpassword, rolvaliduntil, rolreplication, rolbypassrls, pg_catalog.shobj_description(oid, 'pg_authid') as rolcomment, rolname = current_user AS is_current_user FROM pg_authid WHERE rolname !~ '^pg_' ORDER BY 2
```

My first thought was to create a new user with the correct privileges. So, I logged using `heroku pg:psql DATABASE -a my-app-name` then tried `create user myUser with password 'mypassword'` but got the error `ERROR:  permission denied to create role`

I'm honestly not sure what's going on I'm kind of just guessing. Any troubleshooting ideas would be appreciated! (in the meantime I'm just trying to learn more about Postgres)

Comment: If you are using the hobby/shared tier, you cannot use pg_dumpall, as that would obtain other people's data.  If you are paying for dedicated server, you are also paying for support, aren't you?

Comment: I am on "hobby basic" on Heroku Postgres here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans it doesn't say anything about the limitation you cited. Any links on that?

Answer (score 6):

If your problem is just about the `pg_authid` catalog, you should be able to use recent versions of `pg_dumpall` with the `--no-role-passwords` [option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-pg-dumpall.html).

This commonly works in hosted environments where `pg_authid` is inaccesible, e.g. on AWS. The only downside is that the passwords of Postgres users will be missing from the dump.

However, you appear to have a more limited, perhaps shared environment, where you can't even create new Postgres users. I am not certain if there is any chance to get `pg_dumpall` working there.

Comment: `--no-role-passwords` is the correct solution to this issue.  Thank you!!
 
Note: If `pg_dumpall` gives you this error `pg_dumpall: error: could not connect to database "template1": FATAL:  permission denied for database "template1"`, then that means you need to add a `--database` flag (even if you use `--dbname`).